# CentOS 8: How to add a user to a cgroups?

Tags: centos, cgroups

How to add a user to a cgroups in CentOS 8?

Comment: You can only move processes into control groups. What do you want to achieve by moving a user into a control group?

Comment: @Wieland I want to limit a user's RAM usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you to create `systemd slice` for user:

Get `uid` of user:

```
id <user>
```

After that, add next options for [`/etc/systemd/system/<uid>.slice`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.slice.html):

```
[Slice]
MemoryAccounting=true
MemoryLimit=<how_many_memory>M
```

During next login of user slice `<uid>-slice` will be created:

```
systemctl -t slice
```

Comment: Might want to use user-<uid>.slice, that’s what systemd-logind uses.